# Java Regular expression for special characters across all languages

Tags: java, regex

In my user input field, I want to allow a combination of certain special characters, letters and numbers. I should make sure that a regular expression pattern allows this set when typed from **any language**. Basically this regular expression that I have constructed, should support unicode representations also. How do I achieve this using Pattern class in Java?

Sample code that I tried is given here. But this does not cover letters/numbers in any other language apart from English.

```
private static final String ADDRESS_LINE_PATTERN = "[A-Za-z0-9,\\s#\\-.]+";


    public static boolean isInputValid(String patternToValidate, String input){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternToValidate);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        return b;

    }

public static void main(){
String value = "コロン";
System.out.println("Value:" + value + " - valid? " + isInputValid(ADDRESS_LINE_PATTERN, value));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `\\p{Alnum}` to match any kind of letter or digit from any language.

```
 private static final String ADDRESS_LINE_PATTERN = "[\\p{Alnum},\\s#\\-.]+";
```

See [`Pattern` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! This pattern works fine for all alphanum class across languages. But will it also take care of supporting the mentioned special symbols across all languages? In other words, wiki says that in Japanese, コロン is the equivalent of ":". Even though : is not mentioned here in the regular expression, it is still accepted. I am a little confused. Do special symbols have different encodings in unicode for different languages.

Comment: @VinodJayachandran The word コロン in Japanese is simply the translation of the word "colon" in English. It is a *word*, not a special character. But what exactly are you trying to match? There are a lot of special characters, which ones are valid and which ones are not?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in Unicode *aware* regex engines, the *word* class `\w` will
include all alpha-num's from any language.

You could use the negative of it `\W`in a negative class `[^\W]`, add whatever
you don't want `_`, then *OR* it with special characters you do want.

```
(?U)(?:[^\W_]|[-,.+\s#])+
```

*edit* - re: @nhahtdh comment
Added Java `(?U)` inline modifier for `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`
(I assume correct)

Comment: In Java, you would need `(?U)` or `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` to make `\w` Unicode aware.

Comment: @nhahtdh - Updated. I'm going to get to Java one day, too busy using c++ for now.