# Regex to match foreign characters in Url

Tags: java, regex, url

My regex:

```
\\b((?:https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|])
```

So far this regex matches a url in a string. But this fails when the url contains a cyrillic or  other language characters.

Comment: See this: [Java Regular expression for special characters across all languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188164/java-regular-expression-for-special-characters-across-all-languages)

Answer (score 0):

```
"(^(ht|f)tp(s?)://[0-9a-zA-Z\\p{L}][-.\\w\\p{L}]*(:[0-9])*(/?)([a-zA-Z0-9-.?,:'/\\\\+=&amp;%$#_\\[\\]@!()*;~\\p{L}]*)?$)"
```

This works fine for URLs containing Cyrillic characters too

Comment: `\p{L}` includes `[a-zA-Z]`, and you missed `file` protocol.